# How to sort categories by totals in Lotus Notes View

Tags: lotus-notes

Basically, I wanted to sort in descending order a view by the total number of users subscribed in a document (using column totals). They are categorized by the title of the document.

Example

Document A category has 15 total subscriptions.

Document B category has 20 total subscriptions

Document C category has 4 total subscriptions

In the view they would organize in such a way it would look like this

```
>(Title)   |        Totals     |        User
B          |        20         |
           |                   |        Gerard
           |                   |        ....(more users)
A          |        15         |
           |                   |        Michael
           |                   |        ....(more users)
C          |        4          |
           |                   |        John
           |                   |        ....(more users)
                   --------
                   39
```

I tried ticking sort > descending in the Totals column properties but it doesn't work. Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using XPages you could create a Bean that walks the view to sort the categories then returns the detail based on the sorted categories.

If you are not using XPages then this it is not possible to sort by the view totals.

Answer (score 1):

Add a hidden column in front of the categorized column ("Title").
This column should contain the subscription count, and be sorted the way you like it, but not categorized.

Answer (score 0):

You can scan the view (loop over looking for 'iscategory' or jumping to each category using 'getnextcategory') using a viewnavigator and capture the categorised totals from the category 'entries' - if you save these values into a 'reporting doc' you can create a view of these reports and sort the reports on the total field(s) you saved. Run the process on demand or scheduled with an agent.

Its a bit 'round-about' but depending on your app (db size, performance required, etc, can work ok.